# Histogram,and histogram bounding box

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

would i go about detecting this kind of Moth based on its Histogram.i followed tutorials and i  do i need to calculate it first for the isolated moth and then find that specific histogram in the webcam feed ?
if so, how to search for specific Histogram values  within that picture ?
Also how to go about creating a bounding box around the target ?

https://flic.kr/p/nsqxRr

im looking for help in python opencv .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have a bug Lol

Comment: Lol , yeah its a tricky one :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is:

1) Calculate the histogram of the "isolated moth" and store it.

2) Do [backprojection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html) with your model histogram and the input image. The zones of the image containing the histogram you are looking for should "glow" in the backprojection image.

3) If you want to generate rectangle-shaped regions with the location, use [2D moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments).